# How to know if the keyboard is active on a text input

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, hook, keyboard-hook

I have an application that acts like an on screen keyboard, I need it to know if there is a keyboard cursor (caret) active any where, so the keyboard will set to active.

I have searched for keyboard hooks and winapi, but I couldn't find the proper method to use.

To simplify my problem, I need my application to be active if the user can press on the real keyboard and print text on the computer.

Comment: Isn't that the wrong way round? If you are an on screen keyboard application then your application WOULDN'T need to be active when a keyboard is attached. Sorry, this just smells like you are trying to write a keystroke logger.

Comment: @AlSki: They're asking about the carat. If no text entry control has focus (ie, no carat) then they don't want their keyboard to show.

Comment: @AlSki I did not say that , I gave a simplification not meaning I want to use two keyboards.

Comment: @Deanna what do you mean by (carat) , I do not understand nor find an explanation, Thanks a lot

Comment: @AbdallahNasir The Carat is the flashing cursor when entering text. What you called the keyboard cursor.

Comment: @Deanna: do you mean "caret"?

Comment: @Deanna I thought so, thank you, I have searched a lot, but still I cannot find a solution, thank you, you helped too much with the name so I can search faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy by searching for the caret position, since it should be larger than 0

```
    GUITHREADINFO lpgui = new GUITHREADINFO();
    IntPtr fore = GetForegroundWindow();
    uint tpid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(fore, IntPtr.Zero);
    lpgui.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lpgui.GetType());
    bool flag = GetGUIThreadInfo(tpid, out lpgui);
    WINDOWINFO pwi = new WINDOWINFO();
    pwi.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(pwi.GetType());
    GetWindowInfo((IntPtr)lpgui.hwndCaret, ref pwi);

    if (flag)
    {
        if (!(lpgui.rcCaret.Location.X == 0 && lpgui.rcCaret.Location.Y == 0))
        {


            //TODO

        }
    }
```

Comment: This works well. Note that users will have to gather / import the various methods and objects in the code.

Comment: This only ever works for native windows. It won't work for WPF windows, WinUI windows, or Qt windows. In other words: It won't work *most of the time*. You need to set up a WinEvents hook and use UI Automation.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a workaround, but if you can subscribe to a OnFocusChange event in your environment then you can check the type of control that newly received focus. Depending on if it is a 'keyboardable' type (or is derived from a 'keyboardable' type) you can display or hide your onscreen keyboard.

Comment: I think the purpose is to have a system wide onscreen keyboard, not just for one application.

Comment: I have tried that, but I faced a problem with dealing with handlers from the move focus, since UIAutomation is somehow a headache which I couldn't derive any info from its returned or move focus arguments values. Thanks a lot for replying

Answer (score 0):

Define a `DLLImport` so that you can get the currently focused window handle:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetFocus();
```

Now, you can run this to get that window handle if there is something focused for the keyboard:

```
public static bool ControlIsFocused() 
{
    // To get hold of the focused control: 
    IntPtr focusedHandle = GetFocus(); 
    return focusedHandle != IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

So, unless it's a control that allows keyboard focus this method should return `IntPtr.Zero`.

Here is a link to the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for replying,, I do not get it where we check about the keyboard focus in the code you provided. Regards,

Comment: @AbdallahNasir, you use the `ControlIsFocused` method when you want to know if there is a control that has focus that allows keyboard input.

Comment: This answer helped me to find that page; http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getfocus The article mentions about finding focused .Net control.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use the [GetCaretPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcaretpos) function?

It says:

> The caret position is always given in the client coordinates of the window that contains the caret.

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.