# C# detect text-box enter event in whole the Windows

Tags: c#, windows, events, enter

Is it possible to write an application in C# that detect every text-box enter events in Microsoft Windows?
For example if the user enter a text-box in the web browser or even Microsoft word and everywhere, the event fires in the application.

Comment: You can't really do this for "Text boxes" as things, but you can use a Low Level Keyboard hook to know about 99% of key presses.

Comment: Probably not in C#. But may be able to use windows API. Take a look at SetWindowsHookEx and EN_SETFOCUS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781059/how-to-know-if-the-keyboard-is-active-on-a-text-input

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for a Keylogger.

http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/

That should help.

Comment: Actually you know there is two languages for windows for countries that doesn't write in English. The problem is that some windows users write in a wrong language and then they see it is wrong so they have to remove all characters and then write in other language. I need to write an application to alarm the user before writing. What is the best solution to do this?

Comment: So when they enter a text box, you need to see what language they're using and compare it to the input language type? That sounds like quite the achievement if you can accomplish that.

Comment: You're right. How can I implement something like this in C#?

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to check the native languages of the running processes and compare them to the current input language. That's the only thing I could think of. I would create a new question with those specifics.

Comment: Does a Key-logger help me to do this? Maybe I need to convert the written characters to other language?

Comment: That would require you to capture what they type, remove it, and then replace it. I would first try to warn the user before attempting that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104924/discussion-between-blue-eyed-behemoth-and-usermat).