# How to determine the current user keyboard focus (e.g. which text box)?

Tags: python, windows, hook, keyboard-events, keyboard-hook

I would like to figure out which UI element (of any other program currently running) currently has the user's keyboard focus - as an example, let's say I'd like to write a small tool that puts a green border around the currently active text field.

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168996/321973) makes me think I could achieve this partially by setting up a hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) to determine where the user clicked, but that would already fail for figuring out where <kbd>TAB</kbd> moved the focus to. I was also thinking about using [pywinauto](/questions/tagged/pywinauto)'s inspection features to determine which UI elements *are* text input fields at all, and maybe there is an inverse `GetFocus` to its `SetFocus`. But all this seems rather hackish and unnecessarily complicated, so I thought I'd stop and ask here first:

> How to find the UI element that currently has the keyboard focus?

Comment: Python answer not necessary, I can use [tag:pywin32] / [tag:win32com] to translate language-agnostic answers

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13448409/321973) sounds like the answer, I'll have to test and Pythonize it...